# Вопрос с библиотекой requests

Tags: python, requests

Как в "fields" передать сразу несколько значений? Хочу добавить значение city в 'fields'

````
response = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get', params={
    'access_token': token,
    'v': 5.89,
    'user_ids': ids,
    'fields': 'verified'
})```
````

Comment: requests тут абсолютно ни при чём, в [документации ВК](https://vk.com/dev/users.get) написано «список слов, разделенных через запятую»

Comment: Как я в словаре могу использовать запятые для одного ключа, я не понимаю

Comment: Не в словаре, а просто в строке `'fields': 'verified,city'`

Comment: Уже пробовал, не выходит так

Comment: Какое получаемое поведение, когда делаете, как написано в документации? Что именно означает "не выходит так"? Используйте кнопку "править" и добавляйте эту информацию в текст вопроса.